# Jenkins: MatrixCombinationsParameterValue from a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm want to start a matrix-build from a pipeline job but I want to build only one Axis.

I tried with this:

```
build job: "Build_Android_Matrix", propagate: false, wait: true,
    parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'branch', value: "$branch"],
                 [$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'production', value: true],
                 [$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'beta', value: false],
                 [$class: 'MatrixCombinationsParameterValue', name: 'paramFilter', description: null, combinations: ['buildType=Release']]]
```

I have 2 Axes, `flavor` and `buildType`, and `paramFilter` is the matrix combinations parameter.

The matrix-build starts with all the job parameters but it builds nothing because the matrix combinations selection is empty.

I've also tried with `['buildType==Release']` and `['buildType=="Release"']` but I always get the same result.

I've also tried with:

```
build job: "Build_Android_Matrix", propagate: false, wait: true, parameters: [
        new hudson.plugins.matrix_configuration_parameter.MatrixCombinationsParameterValue
        ("paramFilter",
        null,
        ['buildType=Release'])
        ]
```

but it fails because `RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new`.

I'm almost sure that I'm not providing the combinations in the right way but I don't know what else I can try.

**Update**

After Christopher Orr answer I tried to set the parameters like this:

```
[$class: 'MatrixCombinationsParameterValue', name: 'paramFilter', description: null, combinations: ['buildType=Release,flavor=Italy']]]
```

with this as my Axes:

- flavor: Germany Italy Mexico UnitedStates
- buildType: Debug Release

And was not working because I forgot that I have also a Slaves Axis and that must be specified as well.

So this is what worked for me:

```
[$class: 'MatrixCombinationsParameterValue', combinations: ["buildType=Release,flavor=Italy,label=android"], description: '', name: 'paramFilter']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the Matrix Combinations plugin from the web UI, you need to explicitly specify all of the combinations that you want to run.  So in Pipeline you need to do the same, for example:

```
combinations: ['buildType=Release,flavor=beta',
               'buildType=Release,flavor=production']
```

Order of parameters matters.